# How do I find the index of a character in a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, indexing

If I have `str = 'abcdefg'`, how do I find the index of **c** in this string using Ruby?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
index(substring [, offset]) → fixnum or nil
index(regexp [, offset]) → fixnum or nil
```

Returns the index of the first occurrence of the given substring or pattern (regexp) in str. Returns nil if not found. If the second parameter is present, it specifies the position in the string to begin the search.

```
"hello".index('e')             #=> 1
"hello".index('lo')            #=> 3
"hello".index('a')             #=> nil
"hello".index(?e)              #=> 1
"hello".index(/[aeiou]/, -3)   #=> 4
```

Check out [ruby documents](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) for more information.

Comment: just for the sake of completeness rindex() returns the last occurrence:

Returns the index of the last occurrence of the given substring or pattern (regexp) in str. Returns nil if not found. If the second parameter is present, it specifies the position in the string to end the search—characters beyond this point will not be considered.

[same source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html)

Answer (score 28):

You can use this

```
"abcdefg".index('c')   #=> 2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
str="abcdef"

str.index('c') #=> 2 #String matching approach
str=~/c/ #=> 2 #Regexp approach 
$~ #=> #<MatchData "c">
```

Hope it helps. :)